# python: get object arg and check NPE in one line

Tags: python, nullpointerexception

I have a method `foo()` which eventually returns a `Student` named *john*.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from random import randint
class Student(object):
    name = ""

def foo():
    if randint(0,1) == 0:
        student = Student()
        student.name = 'john'
    else:
        student = None
    return student
```

I want to get the name of the student returned by `foo()` (avoiding NPEs and avoiding several calls to `foo()`).

My actual solution  is:

```
student = foo()
print(student.name if student is not None else None)
```

Is it possible to do this in one line, and without creating a temporary variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getattr(obj, 'attr_to_get', default_value)`.

In your example, the solution would be `getattr(foo(), 'name', None)`.

Comment: Thanks, now what if I want for example pass the arg through a dictionary, like: `dic[getattr(foo(), 'name', None)]` (here I get a key error: None)

Comment: Use `dict.get('attr', default)`. So `dict.get(getattr(foo(), 'name', None), None)`. But you should probably not try to golf so hard - sometimes readability trumps code compactness.